# How to find last(sum(count)) in influxdb?

Tags: influxdb

Here in my db measurement, the tags are "source", "edition", "date" and the field is "count".

Each source has multiple editions. I am pushing data on the basis of editions.

I want the sum of editions for each source. I can get it by the normal query.

But here I want this for multiple dates. It is also possible by using nested functions or function of functions.

`select mean(sum),last(sum) from (select sum(count) from epaper_edition where (date='2017-11-03' or date='2017-11-04' or date='2017-11-05' or date='2017-11-06') group by date,source) group by source`

---

`last()` function is based on timestamp.
The `last(sum(count))` results in random `sum(count)`, not the Last one.

I have a solution by using a separate query `sum(count)` for the last date. I need it on one query.

Thanking you advance for giving me a better solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want sums of individual editions per source, you need to group by edition as well as source.

`select mean(sum),last(sum) 
from (select sum(count) from epaper_edition where (date='2017-11-03' or date='2017-11-04' or date='2017-11-05' or date='2017-11-06') 
group by date, source, edition) 
group by source, edition`